# Recommended diagnostic steps to determine why xampp.desktop shortcut won’t launch?

Tags: shortcuts, xampp

When I click on the xampp [custom shortcut](https://junise.wordpress.com/2017/07/23/xampp-in-ubuntu-desktop-shortcut-launcher-entry-home-folder-shortcut-inside-htdocs/) icon in the start menu, nothing happens. I am able to successfully launch the it from terminal though by executing ‘sudo /opt/lamp/manager-linux-64.run’. I will admit, I don’t know what the ‘processes’ name of it is when I open System Monitor.

The following is the configuration text file I wrote:

```
kaign@kaign:/usr/share/applications$ gedit xampp.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

I then verified the owner of the file and changed it from root to my admin account:

```
kaign@kaign:/usr/share/applications$ ls -l xampp.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 root root 217 Dec 29 17:03 xampp.desktop

kaign@kaign:~$ sudo chown -R kaign: /usr/share/applications/xampp.desktop

kaign@kaign:/usr/share/applications$ ls -l xampp.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 kaign kaign 217 Dec 29 17:03 xampp.desktop
```

I've navigated to the GUI folder locations and ensure that the ‘.desktop’ file can be executed as a program

[image: manager file]
[image: run as program]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no answer to your specific question because, with all your documentation, you are diagnosing quite fine as is. However, as to why you do not see anything happening, in the pages you link, it says "gksudo". You, however, use "sudo". When launched from a .desktop launcher, that executable will be running in the background, not connected to standard output nor input. `sudo` is waiting there for your password. It will no come because you do not see its question for the password, and `sudo` will not receive your key presses. The current alternative for invoking a graphical dialog to ask for the `sudo` password is `pkexec`.